# listBoxes troubling in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, wpf-controls

I am working on a project using WPF and C#. On a window, I have around 7 listBoxes, which contain equal number of Items. These items are actually related to each other. It is similar to a grid.

```
lisBox1 | lisBox2 | lisBox3 | lisBox4 | lisBox5 | lisBox6 | lisBox7
```

> Whenever the SelectedIndex of the Third ListBox is changed, all
>   the other listboxes' SelectedIndex is set set equal to the
>   SelectedIndex of the third listBox. This allows user to highlight
>   which row the user is actually reading.

[image: Screenshot from my machine]

When I deployed the project on Client's machine running Windows XP, the Index are not well managed! Each listBox's indexes change regularly and I cannot get the index of the selected Item from all the listBoxes i.e Each listBox may/may not have different index.

Also I have noticed that at client's machine, the listboxes are capable of selecting multiple items, which I have disable and working fine in my development machine running VS10 and Windows 8.

> Is it something related to Windows XP?

Please suggest me what can be the causes of these issues? Any ideas to resolve would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

MarkUp

```
<ListBox Height="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,201,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" FontStyle="Italic" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged" />
<ListBox Height="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="75,201,0,0" Name="listBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85" FontStyle="Italic" SelectionChanged="listBox2_SelectionChanged" />
<ListBox Height="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="163,201,0,0" Name="listBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" SelectionChanged="listBox3_SelectionChanged" KeyDown="listBox3_KeyDown" />
<ListBox Height="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="355,201,0,0" Name="listBox4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" FontStyle="Italic" SelectionChanged="listBox4_SelectionChanged" />
<ListBox Height="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="449,201,0,0" Name="listBox5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="55" FontStyle="Italic" SelectionChanged="listBox5_SelectionChanged" />
<ListBox Height="auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="505,201,0,0" Name="listBox6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" FontWeight="Bold" SelectionChanged="listBox6_SelectionChanged" />
<ListBox Height="auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="590,201,0,0" Name="listBox7" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" FontWeight="Bold" SelectionChanged="listBox7_SelectionChanged" />
<ListBox Height="auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="675,201,0,0" Name="listBox8" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="95" FontWeight="Bold" SelectionChanged="listBox8_SelectionChanged" />
```

Code:

```
private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    listBox2.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
}

private void listBox2_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    listBox3.SelectedIndex = listBox2.SelectedIndex;
}

private void listBox3_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    listBox4.SelectedIndex = listBox3.SelectedIndex;
}

private void listBox4_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    listBox5.SelectedIndex = listBox4.SelectedIndex;
}

private void listBox5_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    listBox6.SelectedIndex = listBox5.SelectedIndex;
}

private void listBox6_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    listBox7.SelectedIndex = listBox6.SelectedIndex;
}

private void listBox7_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    listBox8.SelectedIndex = listBox7.SelectedIndex;
}
private void listBox8_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox8.SelectedIndex;
        }
```

[image: How Indexes Should Be] This is how it is on my pc, Perfect!

[image: How Indexes are on Windows XP] This is how it becomes on XP.

[image: How multiselect is Ok on my machine] This is how multiselect is OFF on my pc and works fine.

[image: How multiselect malfunctioned on Windows XP] This is how multiselect is ON and the first item in listbox3 is always selected on Windows XP.

Comment: Totally unclear what the issue is and what your question is.

Comment: Let me post a screenshot. Please wait.

Comment: In the screenshot, all the listBoxes have equal SelectedIndex and this is how I want it to be! but on my client's machine, all the Indexes are not equal! They change randomly.

Comment: The code is huge, any specific part of the code that you may wish?

Comment: Show us the code for one of the selected index binding, and the code relevant to making sure all the indexes are the same

Comment: You need to do some kind of debugging here, it's not evident you've made any attempt at it yet. You've still not included enough code for us to make any kind of guess at what the issue is. If you have to ask US what part of the code we want, then you haven't done enough work to narrow down where the issue is. We don't know your code.

Comment: The code seems to work perfect on my machine, I am here to ask Experts about what can cause the issue on a Windows XP machine. Posted the code, please have a look.

Comment: ... and please format code correctly.

Comment: Ok from what I am reading you are attempting to cascade the changing of the SelectedIndex when any of the listboxes have their value changed. Are you aware that they will only be the same if you change the first one? If you make a change to the 4th listbox then only listboxes 5,6 and 7 will get updated with the new index.
Unless you forgot to paste in the code for when listbox8 changes?

Comment: where do you bind the data to your listboxes?  Have you considered using a listview with multiple columns instead, your current solution seems a bit overly complicated.

Comment: Yes I know that! The listBox1 and listBox2 are irrelevant! The third listbox, listBox3, is the MASTER listbox that should change the index of rest of the listBoxes.

Comment: Try setting the selection property on the list boxes explicitly using `SelectionMode="Single"`. This is the default selection mode but the list boxes could be inheriting from a parent control...

Comment: @RobJohnson Sir, with due respect, I am new to WPF and I found this easy and straight, may be I'll learn that in future but this has never been an issue. I always works for me. Also No databinding is done, I have fetched data from database and added it to the listBoxes in a loop.

Comment: I am so intended to make sure if this is a Windows XP issue.

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal ok, but unless there is a method in the coded behind for when listbox8 has its value changed (e.g. `listBox8_SelectionChanged`) then listbox 1 and 2 will never get updated when you updated listbox3. Is there a method for listbox8 that you forgot to post? If so it would help to post that so we do not go down the wrong direction with this

Comment: No I really don't have to care about listbox 1 and 2. I have nothing in my listbox8_SelectionChanged Method. I just have to care about listBoxes 3 to 8 where 3rd one is the Master!

Comment: And I quote 
"Whenever the SelectedIndex of the Third ListBox is changed, all the other listboxes' SelectedIndex is set set equal to the SelectedIndex of the third listBox. This allows user to highlight which row the user is actually reading."
So that statement is wrong? What you actually mean is that when listbox 3 is updated all of the listboxes except 1 and 2 will be updated with the latest selectedIndex from listbox 3?
Look I am trying to help you. But you need to clarify the problem and help me help you.

Comment: Ok. I have edited the code. I am understanding that you are trying a lot to understand my problem but adding `private void listBox8_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox8.SelectedIndex;
        }
` isn't helping either in listBox8_SelectionChanged. BTW I have added it.

Comment: What is the code for the `listBox3_KeyDown`?

Comment: From what I've read, I'm not really convinced that this is a XP issue. Are you sure that it's not just the person on the client machine doing something you don't expect? Also, the reason people are concerned about the code structure is because what you have here is completely unmaintainable. That's an absolute nightmare for anyone other than you to try to navigate and debug.

Comment: I agree, I cannot see how this could be an XP issue. I honestly think the problem is that the application worked based on your tests but when it went out to a real user it failed. This happens all the time.

Comment: Sir @tnw, this logic has always worked for me and its working fine on my machine running windows 8. I also checked for any pressed keys on the keyboard on client side but found nothing.

Comment: Just a couple of questions: 1) why don't you use any grid control (e.g., `DataGrid`)? 2) have you read anything about data binding?

Comment: Additionally, by refactoring to code that actually makes sense and is readable, you'll likely find the issue.

Comment: Do you have an XP environment to test on. How do you know that the problem is not solved by adding the `listBox8_SelectionChanged`?

Comment: I did that today! I am just back from the client's site. Also copied there database files to check on my machine, which is so not likely to cause the issue.

Comment: @Dennis I already said that I am comfortable this way and resolving the issue is important, I also know there are other better alternatives. I am new to WPF and C#.

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal I am not trying to sound condescending. I am merely asking the questions I am to try to get to the bottom of your issue. I am assume this is what you want me to do based on your decision to post on SO. To clarify. You did not have that `listBox8_SelectionChanged` method when the application went to site before. But you added it and have since gone to the site and tested to make sure the new code works? Is has not, therefore the problem is something different?

Comment: Yes, I added that and made sure that it did not solve the issue today. I found it irrelevant and therefore I didn't posted that extra code. I am now planning to install Windows 7 on client's site.

Comment: I hope you're joking. Requiring a client to update their entire operating system rather than actually fixing your code is absurd.

Comment: I believe the windows version is a red herring. You need to investigate some of the other suggestions. As it was stated your current code is  not matainable

Comment: Sir, I am looking for a solution and appreciated everybody's efforts here. But I have that option of updating the OS as my client uses that System just to run my app.

Comment: I have flagged this question for the higher ups to sort out.

Comment: Why not put _all_ the listbox index changes you want in `listBox3_SelectionChanged` and set every index to `listBox3.SelectedIndex`? This cascading is rather pointless.

Comment: And I agree with @tnw, if I was your client, I would rather go find a different bank than upgrade my OS just to work with your software. Fix your code, not update your clients' OS.

Comment: It is to make sure that if client mistakenly focuses on any other listBox that can handled.

Comment: I don't understand why people are revolving around the question and issue! The issue is made pretty clear and need assistance not alternatives.

Comment: `[offtopic]`38 comments... wow.`[/offtopic]`.

Comment: I have tried hard to give you assistance. Others have tried the path of offering alternatives but you want a quick and dirty fix to quick and dirty code. That attitude to software development wont get you very far in the industry or on this site. I think we all agree the problem is with your code and not the OS. It seems to me that the user has uncovered bugs in your app that will not disappear when you use your silver bullet and change their OS. I dearly hope they are not paying you for Windows 7, or your effort in installing it.

Comment: I prepared a Windows XP machine and tried my package on that machine. Similar issues were encountered. Then I upgraded it to Service Pack 3 and the problem was still there. Now preparing another machine with Windows 7.

Comment: Same problem on a Clean Installation of Windows 7.

Comment: I have edited and tried ti make the problem a lot clearer! Please suggest ne what can i do.

Comment: We already did suggest what you can do. The problem obviously has nothing to do with the OS, but with your code.

Comment: The problem is not occuring on my development machine, even then why do you think it is my code that is causing the issue?

Comment: What framework does your application target? I know you have installed 4.0 on your own machine and client's but if you are _targeting_ 4.5 on your build, then you'd have issues on XP.

Comment: No, I am very sure that It does not go in an endless loop. When `listbox1` is retriggered by `listbox8` method, index remains same and hence it does not call `selection changed` method anymore.
Yes, I agree with you that Win8 has some optimizations which makes the app run well on my machine. It is related to WPF Listbox control which messes up whenever there are duplicate entries in the listbox controls. I will post an answer very soon. Still Working.

Comment: I have target framework set to .Net Framework 4.0 Full. I am very sure of it because I changed it from .Net 4.0 Client Profile to Full Profile.

Comment: Sorry, you are right and I've been jumping to conclusions. But anyways, [check this out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged.aspx) and look at the platform section, it doesn't list Windows XP, which may be the issue at hand.

Comment: Why can't I post an answer? I have found it.

Answer (score 1):

If all the listboxes are bound to the same collection, you can use the [IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem.aspx) 
property. if you set it to true on all of them, and bind all the listboxes to the same collection, they should be aligned.

As for the multiple selection, you haven't specified [SelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selectionmode.aspx). Try to set it explicitly to Single.

Regards,
Yoni.

Comment: Another Alternative. I will try and post back soon.

Comment: Please check the screenshot with multiselect problem. It even happened after I added `SelectionMode="Single"` to all the listBoxes.

Comment: That's odd, to say the least. I thought the default SelectionMode might have change between versions, and that's what causing the behavior. There _shouldn't_ be any difference between operating systems, but make sure both machines run the same version of .Net framework. Also, try to [snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) the application at the client. See if you can discover the difference.

Comment: Sir, I am sure that I have installed .Net Framework 4.0 Full n both the machines. I have also prepared a machine with Windows XP and installed my package on it. Same problem exists there!

Comment: Are there any specific prerequisites for an WPF App? I installed SQLExpress version, .NET Framework 4.0 Full and the CR Runtime Engine. And Yes, I also installed Windows Imaging Component because .Net Framework was not installing without it.

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal, WPF only needs .Net 3.0 or higher, but it's important that the on your machine and the client's match. At this point I recommend you use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to check the application at the client's and see if there's any difference. if you manage to reproduce the problem on a machine with VS, look at debug output to see any binding failures and other WPF exceptions. Remember that WPF doesn't throw exceptions to the user, it only prints it out to debug. One last thing to check is that what you do with the selected item/index. If you bind them that could be it

Comment: I use selected Items are parameters to open next window when user presses enter over any item! And Yes, I tried on my Windows XP machine and Snoop failed to run.

Comment: Why did snoop fail? It doesn't require anything except WPF. The problems could be related, do you have any exception or log details about snoop?

Comment: Umm, No, I tried to install Snoop, it failed and asked for .NET framework 2.0, I then installed .Net Framework 2.0 also and then It installed successfully. When I ran it, I crashed and showed me "Send Error Report" Error!

Comment: Hmm.. I really don't know what to tell you. You can try to install the latest [C++ Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679). But other than that, I don't know what could cause it. You can try to enable and look at [fusion log](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx).

Comment: I installed latest C++ Redist.
Sure I will.